# How do I run my Go backend and React frontend together locally?

Tags: reactjs, go

Having trouble running my full stack app locally, even when the frontend and backend appear to function on their own just fine.
I created a new app using create-react-app, then added my main.go file. Here's my code:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    port := 8080

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))
    http.Handle("/public", http.StripPrefix("/", fs))

    fmt.Println(`Listening on port:`, port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), fs))
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js" type="text/jsx"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.jsx

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Hi :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm using GoLand as my IDE, and have my build config to run `npm build` before launch. I don't get any Go errors running my build from my IDE, but I do see http 400 errors for `GEThttp://localhost:8080/%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png` and `GEThttp://localhost:8080/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico` in the console. However, there's no other console errors, and I don't see anything in my browser.

When I change my index.html to be:

```
...
<div id="root"><p>Hello world</p></div>
...
```

I can now see "Hello world", so I don't believe it's my Go backend not serving the index.html file correctly.

Also, when I run npm start from my terminal, my App component renders correctly, but obviously without my Go backend running.

I've been really banging my head trying to get my Go and React to be runnable and debuggable together locally, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. How can I get my whole app to play nicely together?

Comment: your backend work should `not` host `/public`, should host `/build` instead, webpack will pack your project into `/build` by `default`.

Comment: @Mee that did the trick, thank you so much! Looks like I have some more reading up on webpack to do.